# Get a list image urls from inside of a <div>

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

I am trying to use HtmlAgilityPack to obtain the image src="" value from a group of images on a webpage and add them to a list of strings.

I have tried the following but I don't get back the img tags.

```
    Dim htmlDoc As New HtmlDocument()

    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(GetPage(New Uri(product.Link)))

    For Each imageShow As HtmlNode In htmlDoc.GetElementbyId("slideShow").ChildNodes

        For Each image In imageShow.Elements("img")
            Console.WriteLine(image.Attributes("src").Value)
            product.OtherImages.Add(image.Attributes("src").Value)
        Next

    Next
```

The webpage is as follows.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ....
        <div id="slideShow" class="slideShow">
            <div class="slides">
                <div class="slide">
                    <a href="http://mywebsite.com/images/some1.jpg">
                        <img src="http://mywebsite.com/images/some1.jpg" />
                    </a>
                <div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <a href="http://mywebsite.com/images/some2.jpg">
                        <img src="http://mywebsite.com/images/some2.jpg" />
                    </a>
                <div>
                ...
            </div>
        <div>
        ....
    </body>
</html>
```

I was expecting the image.Attributes("src").Value to be "http://mywebsite.com/images/some1.jpg"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know about the xPath component and was able to select nodes using the expressions below.

```
    Dim htmlDoc As New HtmlDocument()

    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(GetPage(New Uri(product.Link)))

    For Each slidesNode In htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='slideShow']//div[@class='slides']")

        For Each slide In slidesNode.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='slide']")
            Console.WriteLine(slide.SelectSingleNode(".//a//img").Attributes("src").Value)
        Next

    Next
```

I wasn't sure if there was a quicker or better way to access each image in the slide node, but this seems to work for now.